# Is there a verb for "telling the truth"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Why is there no set word that means "to tell the truth"? We have a word for telling something that is not truthful, a.k.a. to lie, but why is there no conjugatable term for telling the truth?

In Latin, the word for truth is veritas. In English, we have words like verify, which means to validate the truth of something.

So why not have a word that means to tell the truth instead of saying "tell the truth"?

> I'm telling the truth.
>
> I'm X-ing.

Comment: The concept is so rare that there's not been a need to invent a term.

Comment: [Related question (single word request for opposite of lying)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161550/antonym-for-lying)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as @nohat has said, "I get pretty anxious when I see questions like this one, where there is (to my knowledge) no real answer, and ... people [are taking] this as an invitation to start coining words.
I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word invented [or to invent a 'word']. While I delight in exciting new words ...

Comment: being invented and promulgated, I think we will rapidly lose our reputation as a place where people can get authoritative answers if many answers are not authoritative but just merely inventive."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm absolutely for you. I can remember about two years ago I said the same thing, but you know what the answer was? "That's the way all words invented".  And I didn't know what to say.

Comment: I wanted to flag the question, but I wondered if it was blatantly off-topic. I think we need another option. :)

Comment: @haha 'That's the way all words  [were/are] invented' is rubbish if you are speaking about an earlier ELU post.  The coiners use candidate words in a work of fiction, or introduce terminology in a scientific paper where they feel the need to introduce or define terminology. They risk their own sales / reputation. They don't abuse sites like ELU where this is specifically off-topic as a convenient and less exacting platform, a back-door approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antonym for lying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161550/antonym-for-lying)

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole bunch of legal terms for this.  All are fair game, but because we use the terms so rarely in spoken speech they sound stiff, formal, and long.

'Aver' is in the link referenced above.  That's probably closest to what you ask.

'Represents' or 'warrants' (often combined into the phrase 'represents and warrants') means statement following is identified as truthful.  'Attest' also means to state something truthfully.